# Creating two or more CEF browser windows

Tags: c++, chromium

I have been suffering for two weeks, please help me:

And I use the built-in CEF example - "cefsimple" - it works fine: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/tests/cefsimple/?at=master

The "cefsimple" example creates a browser window and opens the specified URL in it.

But as soon as I add another browser window creation feature:

```
CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(window_info, my_browser_handler_, "google.com", browser_settings, nullptr, nullptr);
```

That's where the problems happen.
The second browser window is being created, BUT a problem occurs - the two created windows seem to blink constantly, as if switching between each other very quickly.

I tried the advice - install:

```
window_info.ex_style = WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
```

But it doesn't help at all.

Maybe someone has created more than one window browser in CEF ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but our application that loads two different web pages in CEF windows, loads each of them as their own application.  Our main app launches two instances of "CefWin.exe", one pointing to URL "A", the other pointing to URL "B".  We then use Windows messaging to communicate between all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encounter this problem recently, and this may help you.

In your native window proc, process WM_SETFOCUS with:

```
if (!::GetFocus())
{
    // set cef focus;
}
```

Without call ::GetFocus(), two cef windows will blink constantly.